# Dissolve by Class in eCognition?

Tags: merge, ecognition

I have a lot of numbered classes in my eCognition project (version 9.0.1), which contains approx. 2 Mio. segments. All segments have been assigned to a class and now I want to merge them (basically do what "Dissolve" in a GIS would do), but would like to avoid inserting "Merge Region" 60 times, opening the input mask for each of them and change the class filter. How can I achieve this "Merge by Class" all at once?